# Is it even possible to make a panel-like React component showing source code with line number and collapsing function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, components

The site now I am developing has a collapsable source code view panel.
And I have no idea how to implement a React component to do the exactly the same thing and I am really sorry that I can only afford an example what I want.

There is a code view panel on [this site](https://ftmscan.com/address/0xce761d788df608bd21bdd59d6f4b54b2e27f25bb#contracts) and I want exactly same panel like the one on this site.

https://ftmscan.com/address/0xce761d788df608bd21bdd59d6f4b54b2e27f25bb#contracts

On the solidity source code view panel there is a collapse function and I am not sure how to implement this function.

Is there any module that can parse solidity code or do I have to make a new logic to parse code?

To summarize my questions;

1. Make a React Component that can view source code.
2. How to add collapse function to that component?

Additionally, I am currently using material-ui 4.12.3 and React version is 17.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they are using the [Ace editor](https://ace.c9.io/).

There are multiple React implementations of the Ace editor on [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=react%20ace). I recommend you look into one of those. (Then you'll also get expand/collapse in the code editor "for free".)